# Linearly independent set definition

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

The definition of a linearly independent set I have been given is:
A set S is linearly independent if every finite subset of S is linearly independent.

Do there exist any sets S such that all finite subsets are linearly independent, but contain an infinite subset that is linearly dependent? If not, why include the 'finite' in the definition?

Comment: No, because the definition says that said infinite subset should contain a finite linearly dependent subset, which is a fortiori a linearly dependent subset of S.

Comment: The definition you were given seems wrong... Linear independence is used to define linear independence... is there some way you can clarify the definition?

Comment: Before this the book defines a collection of vectors as linearly independent if they are not linearly dependent. But then for a set to be linearly independent, the property must not just hold for the set as a whole, but for every finite subset of the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is the usual definition of linear independence of a *finite* set of vectors: namely, $\{v_1,\dots, v_k\}$ is linearly independent if $\lambda_1v_1+\dots +\lambda_kv_k=0$ implies all $\lambda_i=0$.

*Then*, one can extend it for infinite sets, say, by the given definition.

Note that vector addition, hence also linear combination, is defined only for finitely many vectors, so if a vector $u$ is linearly dependent on a set $S$, then it means it is a linear combination of finitely many of them.